# Inconstant gap between border and content

Tags: html, css, border

I am having an issue with a simple container with borders: a small gap appears randomly on any edges between the container's borders and content, which is visible when this content has a background. This snippet sums it up very quickly:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.leftBox {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftBox"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftBox"/></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftBox"/></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftBox"/></div>
</div>
```

And here is a picture of the result I get with Chrome, in case the issue is browser-dependant:

[image]

Any idea of why I get this result? Any workaround? Thanks

EDIT: I found out that I'm getting the same result with any browser BUT only on my laptop screen: no more gap if I display the web page on another device! What kind of witchcraft is this?

EDIT: issue was caused by Windows scaling and thus unrelated to the css I wrote. See answer below.

Comment: Your snippet code already displays the expected result.

Comment: In my browser I guarantee it does not... at least now I know it must be related to the browser? Which one are you using?

Comment: Maybe refresh your browser cache or try another browser.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 91.0.4472.124 on Windows 10 and the code snippet in the question results in the expected result for me.

Comment: Same result with any browser but only on my laptop screen! I moved the browser window to my side screen and the gap disappears... see edit

Comment: Unexpectedly, the gap comes from Windows scaling parameter, and has nothing to do with my browser or css... Thanks for helping me finding out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out where the issue comes from: two screens, same resolution, different result. Only difference between the screens was Windows scale set to 125% on my laptop screen. Problem disappears when I reset it to 100%. Strange behavior! No workaround then I guess, only letting down people with Windows scaling activated...

Comment: For me on Windows 11, it was at 100% originally and I had to change to 125% to fix. Gotta love inconsistencies (sarcasm).

Answer (score 0):

For people that really need a reliable fix, you can set an identical border on the child element, and increase the `z-index` so it is on top of the parent.

I could not replicate the problem within a snippet but hopefully the answer is self explanatory.